How to separate a specific part of the text from a text in golang
guys i want have input and split that one specific part of that
for example
input is : "bla bla bla (asd) bla bla bla"
output is: (asd)
and when found parentheses in my input get it and my output be just "(asd)" and i dont know how to do that and i search about it but i didnt find anything to help me if you know i will be happy to say how can i do that
i expect to my output split when that find parentheses i mean work like
if you find this "(" start catch it until you find this ")" and then add it to a variable and print that variable

What have you tried so far?  Your prose translates to Go code in a straightforward way:   for i, r := range s { if r == '(' { start = i } ...

strings.Index and string slicing.

Is there exactly 1 occurrence of bracketed text in the input?

You can use regexp:
input := "bla bla bla (asd) bla bla bla"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\(.*\)`)
output := re.FindString(input)

